# Android NavigationView dual textColor

Tags: android

I am trying to have a navigation view with two groups where the first group textColor is black and the second group is a lightGrey.

I seem to only be able to specify a single color in the NavigationView xml configuration.

Is there a way to override this behaviour?

My navigation view menu:

```
<group
    android:id="@+id/navGroupMain"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
        android:title="@string/navigation_drawer_item_dashboard" />
</group>

<group
    android:id="@+id/navGroupFooter"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:title="@string/navigation_drawer_item_settings" />
</group>
```

And this is the theme plugged into the NavigationView

```
<style name="AppTheme.ThemeOverlay.NavigationView" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- This is the menu item text color. -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- This is the menu header text color and icon color. -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/grey_500</item>
    <!-- This is the selected color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Post some code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this works, but it is really dirty.
The i[0] < 16 indicates that it should only Change the Background for the first 4 items.

Add it to the end of your onCreate method

```
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
      try {
          Field field = LayoutInflater.class.getDeclaredField("mFactorySet");
          field.setAccessible(true);
          field.setBoolean(layoutInflater, false);
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
        final int[] i = {0};
        LayoutInflaterCompat.setFactory(getLayoutInflater(), new LayoutInflaterFactory() {
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                i[0]++;
                if (i[0] < 16 && name .equalsIgnoreCase("android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView")) {
                    try{
                        LayoutInflater f = getLayoutInflater();
                        final View view = f.createView(name, null, attrs);
                        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                // set the background drawable
                                view .setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

                            }
                        });
                        return view;
                    } catch (InflateException e) {
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
```